# Message box when accessed from iPad

Tags: conditional-content

I am still looking for a solution for this and can't seem to find it. I have the following code to start, but am not sure how to write the function to fire off a .js file. I need this to work on one specific page ID.

```
function ipad_alert() {
 if( preg_match('/ipad/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {?>
      // link to .js file? 
 <?php }
 }
 add_action('init','ipad_alert');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to add a js file. I've hooked `wp_enqueue_scripts` so I can check `is_page()` for a specific page.

```
function ipad_alert() {
    if( preg_match('/ipad/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && is_page(7) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('my_script', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/js/my_script.js');
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','ipad_alert');
```

Comment: I've tried using that, but I can't seem to get it to work. Here's a knucklehead question. I currently have the HTML that the js is supposed to hook to in the wordpress editor. Could that keep it from working? I didn't know create a specific template page for this because I don't see the need.

Comment: @chris_s - I'm not sure I understand what you mean? I put the above code in my functions.php file and it's working, so I'm not sure what the issue may be without more info.

Comment: I currently have this HTML in the editor in a page.
`<a href="#dialog" name="modal">Simple Modal Window</a>
 
<div id="boxes">
    <!-- #customize your modal window here -->
 
    <div id="dialog" class="window">
        <b>Testing of Modal Window</b>
         
<!-- close button is defined as close class -->
        <a href="#" class="close">Close it</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Do not remove div#mask, because you'll need it to fill the whole screen --> 
    <div id="mask"></div>
</div>`
Can I get this to work if it's in the editor?